# getInstalledPackages issues in Android simulator / device 2.2

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

The code above does not give quite every installed package (for instance, it does not give the package this code is running from). The code runs from the main thread, never tried other device / emulator versions besides device / emulator 2.2. Any idea what is wrong ?

Thanks

```
public Map<String, String> getInstalledPackages()
{
    Map<String, String> apps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    List<PackageInfo> appsInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);

    for (PackageInfo appInfo: appsInfo)
    {
        try 
        {
            apps.put(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.versionName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return apps;
}
```

PS: if I try it with pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES) it returns an empty Map - tried on device ony

Answer (score 0):

If I replace

```
List<PackageInfo> appsInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

with

```
List<PackageInfo> appsInfo = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
```

I get the package of my application.